# Is there any plugin for cordova that can record video in the background discretely?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm new for apache cordova/phonegap.I'm creating an app for android. I want to record video in the background discretely while the user will do some tasks. I tried the jamesla/backgroundvideo plugin but the recording video can be seen in the background. Any advices and thank you.

Comment: did you tried Cordova media capture plugin?

Comment: I did but with Cordova media capture plugin the user will start/stop recording the video.

Comment: This was the close one to your requirment. I dint find any readymade plugin that does background recording. Sorry